# Query for extracting info from one table based on other in strongloop

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have two tables post and share, post has many share.   I want to fetch  all data in post table using userId(posted by owner user)  and also check share table using same userid that is if some one shared post to other user, if any condition is true, I need to fetch data.

I want to fetch data in post table if posted by owner or shared by other user in share table.

Example :

**table name: post**

```
id(pk) postname userid
    1  abc       10
    2  xxx       10
    3  yyy       11
    4  zzz       12
    5  bbb       13
```

**table name:share**

```
id postid(fk) userid
1   3           10
2   4           10
3   3           11
4   1           12
```

**Expected output: example find by userid 10**

```
 id postname userid
  1  abc       10  // this record created by user 10 (owner)
  2  xxx       10  // this record created by user 10 (owner)
  3  yyy       11  // this record shared by other user to user 10.
  4  zzz       12  // this record shared by other user to user 10.
```

**model relationship:post.json**

```
 "relations": {
    "shares": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "share",
      "foreignKey": "postid"
    }
  }
```

**I tried  following queries but I am getting error**

```
{
  "where": {
    "or": [
      {
        "userid": 10
      },
      {
        "include": {
          "relation": "shares",
          "scope": {
            "where": {
              "userid": 10
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**and // here I just checking postname also but no need for this question.**

```
{
  "where": {
    "or": [
      {
        "userid": 10
      },
      {
        "postname": "xxx"
      }
    ],
    "include": {
      "relation": "shares",
      "scope": {
        "where": {
          "userid": 10
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about skipping the 'formal' relationship and just use an operation hook (https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Operation+hooks) such that when you do a find, you can manipulate the results?

Comment: you mean separate call for post and share , finally concatenate both data ?

Comment: What I mean is - when a find operation is called, in theory you can append to it the shared posts.